# Excel sheet is not exporting

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, asp.net

I need to generate excel report based on the dates selected. Every things works fine but my excel sheet is not generating but its working fine when i try to export in web forms. But if i use master page and content page its not working..

here is my code

aspx

```
<center>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Start Date:" style="color:white"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="datepicker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="../Images/calendar.gif" id ="datepic"/>
            <cc1:calendarextender ID="ceFromDate" runat="server" TargetControlID="datepicker"
                                                        Format="dd-MMM-yyyy" Enabled="True" PopupButtonID="datepic" CssClass="black">
                                                    </cc1:calendarextender>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <br />
    <br />
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="End Date:" style="color:white"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="datepicker1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
          <img src="../Images/calendar.gif" id="datepic1" />
            <cc1:calendarextender ID="Calendarextender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="datepicker1"
                                                        Format="dd-MMM-yyyy" Enabled="True" PopupButtonID="datepic1" CssClass="black">
                                                    </cc1:calendarextender>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Get Report" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ></asp:GridView>
    </center>
```

***cs code:***

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr))
    {
        //for getting id
        con.Open();


        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select adcomplain_no as \"AD COMPLAIN NO\",to_char( COMPLAINT_DATE,'DD/MM/YY') as \"COMPLAINT DATE\",nature_of_complaint as \"NATURE OF COMPLAINT\",(select categoryname from crs_categorynew where crsid=complaint_categoryID)as \"CATEGORY NAME\",(SELECT subcategoryname FROM CRS_SUDCATEGORYNEW WHERE CRSSUBID=complaint_subcategory) as \"SUB CATEGORY NAME\",seat_location AS \"SEAT LOCATION\",seatno AS \"SEAT NO\",extensionno AS \"EXTENSION NO\",to_char(entry_date,'DD/MM/YY')as \"ENTRY DATE\" ,(select staffno||'-'||NAME as name from employee where staffno=entry_by) as \"ENTRY BY\" ,(CASE STATUSFLAG WHEN 'U' THEN 'Un Allotted' WHEN 'AN' THEN 'Allotted' WHEN 'B' THEN 'Being Completed' WHEN 'C' THEN 'Completed' WHEN 'UA' THEN 'Un Attented' ELSE '' END)as \"STATUS\",(select staffno||'-'||NAME as name from employee where staffno=alloted_person) as \"ALLOTED PERSON\",to_char(target_date,'DD/MM/YY') as \"TARGET DATE\",(select staffno||'-'||NAME as name from employee where staffno=alloted_by) as \"ALLOTED BY\",to_char(alloted_date,'DD/MM/YY') as \" ALLOTED DATE\",complain_reason as SOLUTION,to_char(complain_statusdate, 'DD/MM/YY')as \"COMPLAIN STATUS DATE\",(select staffno||'-'||NAME as name from employee where staffno=complain_statusby)AS \"COMPLAIN STATUS BY\" from crs_complaint where complaint_date between (TO_DATE('" + datepicker.Text + "', 'dd/mm/yyyy')) and (TO_DATE('" + datepicker1.Text + "', 'dd/mm/yyyy'))", con);
        OracleDataAdapter oda = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        oda.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
         "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            //Apply text style to each Row
            GridView1.Rows[i].Attributes.Add("class", "textmode");
        }
        GridView1.RenderControl(hw);


        string headerTable = @"<h1>Service Request List from '" + datepicker.Text + "' to '" + datepicker1.Text + "'</h1>";
        //style to format numbers to string
        string style = @"<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";
        //Range rg = (Excel.Range)worksheetobject.Cells[1, 1];
        //rg.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY";
        Response.Write(headerTable);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();

        con.Close();




    }
}
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
    /* Confirms that an HtmlForm control is rendered for the specified ASP.NET
       server control at run time. */
}
```

Comment: Define `not working`. Do you get an error, an empty sheet, wrong data? Without more detailed info your question is not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

cretae a trigger for the button in updatepanel, this may solve your problem..

```
</ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
        </Triggers>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: just for testing you can try to saprate the both function.....take two buttons,  bind gridview on first button click and export it into excel on second button click...i am using the same with master page and update panel